# How to get count of number of rows where one of the columns entry is the same

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

First, sorry for a bad title, I don't really know what this is called.

I know that I can use `context.Model.Where(a => a.Entity == "example").Count()`. But I want something more generic where I can get a count of how many rows have the same entry in one of the columns. A pic of what I mean: [image]

My end result that I wanna get is a list of the count like: 3, 1 etc

Comment: Check out `GroupBy` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `GroupBy` statement for this to group by a value of your items, and then `Select` the result you want from it:

```
var result = await db.Model
        .GroupBy(x => x.Age)
        .Select(g => new {
            Age = g.Key, 
            Count = g.Count(),
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

The result is a list of objects that have an `Age` property with the age value, and a `Count` property with the number of items that had that `Age` value.

[image: Example result]

If you just want the counts, then you can just return those from the `Select` expression directly:

```
var result = await db.Model
        .GroupBy(x => x.Age)
        .Select(g => g.Count())
        .ToListAsync();
```

Note that this will obviously prevent you from saying what age an individual count is representing.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear with how i wanted my result to be. I've updated the post now.

Comment: @aneko5 You can simply change the `Select` to return whatever result you want. If you just want to know the counts (without knowing what age each count represents), then you can just do `.Select(g => g.Count())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `distinct` method and get as anonymous object then applying `count` on it

```
context.Model.Where(a => a.Entity == "example").Select(a = > new {a.User, a.Address, a.Age}).Distinct().Count()
```